# Парсинг динамически подгружаемого контента BS4, lxml, requests

Tags: парсер, requests, bs4, lxml

подскажите куда копать в данной ситуации, есть сайт "https://vk.com/@yvkurse", необходимо спарсить каждую статью из группы. Дело в том, что при скроллинге вниз страницы, контент подгружается динамически. Не могу понять как можно грамотнее сделать, с помощью Селениума? либо отследить запросы в Network и затем повторить их? Подскажите источник, где можно почитать как правильно повторять POST запросы на сервер..
Спасибо заранее

Comment: Если без селениума, то смотреть какие запросы (ajax) идут на сервер и повторить их в коде, если с селениумом, то через него листать страницу и анализировать элементы на странице ([мой пример на основе пикабу](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/3918e11e7ee928e2213ee6fb60d35b979735ec97/selenium__examples/pikabu_ru__download_all_images/main.py#L67)). Селениум с динамическими сайтами удобен, но у него есть свои сложности, например обращаясь к элементу для клика нужно чтобы он был в зоне видимости или собирая элементы и после обращаясь к ним может оказаться что они уже не существуют,

Comment: т.к. например сайт удалил элементы (такое в плейлисте яндекс-музыки, [еще пример](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/3918e11e7ee928e2213ee6fb60d35b979735ec97/selenium__examples/music_yandex_ru/get_all_tracks_playlist/variant_2_with_scroll_optimization.py#L49)). А так, скролл выполняется через javascript через `window.scrollTo`. Насчет источников я не подскажу, т.к. изучал парсинг "на месте", в инспекторе браузера можно у запросов посмотреть какой запрос, адрес, заголовки, параметры и данные отправлять. Лучше, от вас получить конкретные вопросы по сайтам

Comment: Спасибо за наводки, буду разбираться)

Comment: Пожалуйста. Как разберетесь с этим, пожалуйста, оформите это в ответе :)